# Telegram Bot is not a constructor • TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, telegram-bot

Why I have This error:
`TypeError: node_telegram_bot_api_1.default is not a constructor`

This is My Code in TypeScript:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/.env'})
console.log('Hello TypeScript')
import TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api';    
const bot = new TelegramBot(process.env.BOT_TOKEN, {polling: true});
```

And This is My Output Code after Compile:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });
console.log('Hello TypeScript');
const node_telegram_bot_api_1 = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
const bot = new node_telegram_bot_api_1.default(process.env.BOT_TOKEN, { polling: true });
```

[image: Photo]

Comment: Looks like the problem is with incorrect import. Have you tried this already `import * as TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api';`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the import is incorrectly done. The documentation of [`node-telegram-bot-api`](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) says that the import needs to be done as follows:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
```

This means that the whole module is being imported, which translates to ES6 import as follows:

```
import * as TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api';
```

For different syntax and semantics of import please refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Thank you @sayan-pal , Solved 

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei Glad it helped :)

Comment: In current version (v0.50.0), the object is a default export so `import TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api';` became correct

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem and I solved it by replacing

```
    const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
```

with

```
    const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')
```

Comment: @anthony what is the problem ? it's work for me